# android - cannot see full screen in emulator landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-orientation

In my android application,I have an activity which has four buttons.When emulator executes in portrait mode it shows all the four buttons,but when i turn it into landscape mode it does not  display all 4 buttons only two buttons are displayed , cannot see the full screen.

what i want to implement is to show all the 4 buttons in landscape mode

Comment: Are these buttons in a vertical layout? Perhaps you need to put them inside a ScrollView? Without more info or details of your xml you'll not get an accurate answer, only guesses.

Comment: NigelK- It will not look good if we put scrollview in app.Its looks good when we put touch slide to move up and down in landscape mode.if you know how to implement slider. please post it.

Comment: Anyone post the layout that works in landscape mode also